# How to draw an EAN-13 barcode in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, barcode, barcode-printing, ean-13

What's the most basic way of drawing EAN-13 barcodes in C# (using Visual Studio 2013) for printing?

I would prefer to include a namespace providing me with the tools to create and output the barcode.

Comment: Using an EAN13 font is the easiest

Comment: @AlexK. Of course you'd have to do the encoding yourself, i.e. translating numbers to symbols, calculating checksums, etc.

Comment: @AlexK, Thorston is right... you can't just print using an EAN-13 font as printing 13 numbers just shows 13 short bar codes instead on 1.  I was down that road a few hours ago pulling out my hair until I figured this out.

Comment: Yes you will always need to apply the correct encoding, I thought you were after alternatives to rendering the glyphs manually

Comment: @Dominique http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10162/Creating-EAN-Barcodes-with-C http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/20/4459.aspx both within the first 5 results from google

Comment: @Thewads congratulations on only taking 5 minutes to find a link to something outdated (2005) that has been mentioned by someone else... oh, did I mention I told you I'm using something recent?

Comment: @Thewads and your second link is from 2006... don't know what that runs on... maybe you should consider an upgrade!

Comment: @Dominique failing to see how the version of VS you are using is at all relevant, not like that changes the logic of how to create barcodes but ok. Use logic, fixup any changes between .net version etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest library to use IMHO is [Aspose BarCode.NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/barcode-component.aspx). You can find examples [here](https://github.com/asposebarcode/Aspose_BarCode_NET)

The library does cost money, but works well enough that for us, it was worth it.

```
// Create an instance of BarCodeBuilder
BarCodeBuilder builder = new BarCodeBuilder();

// Set the symbology type
builder.SymbologyType = Symbology.EAN13;

// Set the codetext
builder.CodeText = "test-123";

// Get the barcode image
Image img = builder.BarCodeImage;
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the image, like save it to a file, or write to a memory stream, etc.:

```
img.Save("path", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I want something free... sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: [Here is](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10162/Creating-EAN-Barcodes-with-C) a possible solution already. Requires some work to integrate into your project, but it's a simple algorithm to generate an EAN-13 in GDI (for printer output for example)